# Column oriented Data of Object in NSTable

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I'm trying to fill my `NSTable` with informations from an object array but column oriented. The default table orientation is by row. So, each object information is presented by row:

[image: row oriented object data in NSTableView]

But I need to present the object information by column:

[image: column oriented object data in NSTableView]

I do not understand how to achieve this. What if the number of columns is variable at runtime and how to show the object data column oriented? The standard `NSDataSourceProtocol` with reusing cells/views is not useful in my case:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {

  var text: String = ""
  var cellIdentifier: String = ""

  guard let item = modelObjectArray?[row] else {
    return nil
  }

   if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[0] {
     let text = item.name
     cellIdentifier = "someIdentifier"
    } else if ...{
       ...
    }

   if let cell = tableView.make(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView {
     cell.textField?.stringValue = text
     return cell
   }
return nil
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: So I think there are two answers here: 1) Build a complicated relational data  source, capable of filling your table, which I don't think you're going to get an answer for, and 2) Use a UICollectionView, which has rows and columns, and is probably what you want. I know that's a bit snarky, but you seem to be doing the old round peg/square hole, thing.

Comment: @dylanthelion, thanks for your honest feedback (not snarky). I was somehow expecting that kind of answer but you know: hope is the last to die. Anyway, I'll certainly have a look for the CollectionView approach. Never thought about that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments saying that you better go for a different architecture (`UICollectionView` could be a best bet indeed) but just for fun let's try to implement your original request.

I've made a lot of assumptions to simplify the code (like all the features are Strings) so if you want to go for it you should adapt to your implementation details.

So, first let create the right model for your table (somewhere in your `viewDidLoad` method or similar):

```
var feat1s = [String]()
var feat2s = [String]()
var feat3s = [String]()

for modelObject in modelObjects {
    feat1s.append(modelObject.feat1)
    feat2s.append(modelObject.feat2)
    feat3s.append(modelObject.feat3)    
}
```

Then, make sure you return the right object for each row/column combination:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {

    let colIndex = tableView.tableColumns.index(of: tableColumn!)!
    switch row {
        case 0: return feat1s[colIndex]
        case 1: return feat2s[colIndex]
        case 2: return feat3s[colIndex]
        default: return nil
    }
}
```

Note that our data source method is returning the String objects and not a `NSTableCellView`. It's easier to use bindings in Interface Builder to "link" the returned object to a field in your cell view template.

If you absolutely want to return fully formatted `NSTableCellView` I would rather use other data source method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
```

Now, this works if you have a fixed number of model objects (thus a fixed number of columns). If you don't know it in advance you could use a dictionary of arrays instead of `feat1s`, `feat2s` etc. and dynamically insert new columns with something like

```
tableView.addTableColumn(tableColumn: NSTableColumn)
```